# Windows 8 RAM Increase

Tags: windows-8, memory

I've been using Windows 8 for a while without any problem on my 8gb i5 system, but all of the sudden, the memory being used has been jumping up to around 6gb on idle. In task manager, the program using the most memory is chrome, at about 90mb. It says the total amount of RAM in use is 2.4gb, but the available RAM is at 1.4gb. Theoretically, it should be upwards of 4gb. I've recently swept my computer with mbam the other day and it found nothing amiss. I'm familiar with Windows caching memory, but my computer has almost crashed on me while running an instance of chrome. If windows were caching effectively, this wouldn't have been a problem. I'm not sure if I've explained well enough, but I'd just like to know if there's a way to curb my memory. It's at 6.5gb right now, and I really just have chrome up.

Thanks

Comment: Start Chrome's task manager (shift-esc in Chrome) and sort by memory. See if you find anything interesting.

Comment: Nothing weird: http://i.imgur.com/g9lys94.png
I don't think it's a chrome problem; the memory is at 6gb even when chrome's closed.

Comment: Post some pictures of RAMMp: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229